# Why does a non-forked ANT Java task not see some required classes?

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I am experiencing this problem where if I start my server application as a forked Java task , it works fine (but annoyingly grabs the System.in()  input)  but when I try to run the Java task as unforked (in order to retain the system input), it cant find some of the classes ( specifically a javax ssl package).

Is this an issue where I need to include a task argument like includeJavaRuntime="true"    or something?  This error suggests to me that the classloader is different when non-forked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a classloader problem. Most likely the jar you need is missing from the system classpath.

It's actually safer to always run Java processes in a separate thread, using a classpath you provide and specify for them.

```
<path id="classpath.id">
        <fileset ...
</path>

<java fork="true" classpathref="classpath.id" ....
```

Comment: I'm 100% sure the class IS in the classpath and 100% sure that doing what you suggest above wont work. I think the problem is a deeper classloader issue... more likely a system policy problem due to the custom classloader of Ant. Still trying to understand. I had a similar issue with an attempt to use Beanshells classloader but got a different error message.